# Dynamic route on vue router

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

My project requires to have a dynamic route for example "mywebsite/{project_name}" so if the user type {project_name} it will check the api and grab the information and then display its UI layout also I need to put "mywebsite/{project_name}/admin" where another UI layout.

Comment: Hi, what did you tried so far? This seems like a good starting point: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html

Comment: Hi thanks this is my first time using vue and  this is a turn over. I already fixed it by doing mywebsite/:project_name.